# Populating a table with the results of a FREETEXT search

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, freetext

I am new to text searching etc and would appreciate any help or guidance with the following problem.

I have set up a Full-Text catalog with specific search words (about 500).

This is an example of my tables

```
id.............| Course...........| cat 
===============|==================|====
1..............| ACE..............| 2     
2..............| CCE..............| 3     
3..............| CCFP.............| 2     
4..............| GIAC.............| 2     
5..............| CDFE.............| 3     
6..............| CFCE.............| 1
```

I have a second table that I store descriptions and documents in:

```
id.....| Descr........| Document 
=======|==============|=========
1......| Advert.......| html     
2......| Book.........| html     
3......| Report.......| html     
4......| Report.......| html     
5......| Book.........| html     
6......| Report.......| html
```

The Document field is currently a blob and stores both pdf, docx and html files in. (I can change it if necessary.)

How would I get the FREETEXT search to search for the words in the catalog which are in the Document field and place the results in a separate table like this:

```
DocID |DocTerm | Status      |CatTermID| Descr  
======|========|=============|=========|================
1     | CHFI   | Notfound    |         |
2     | CCFP   | Exact Match | 3       |
3     | ACE    | Exact Match | 1       |
3     | ACEF   | Notfound    |         |
1     | CDFE   | Exact Match | 5       |
3     | ACE    | Notfound    | 1       |
```

I would really appreciate for your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2016, but also use MYSQL so either. Thanks

Comment: The most important part is to be able to search through a document stored in a table and identify which phrases or words have been found and which have been missed. Thanks